# Django how to get admin full name

Tags: python, html, django

I have a model named Post, and want to save the full name of the admin automatically who created(or edited) that post.
I read about get_full_name() in django documentation, but I cannot understand how to call this method.
Here is my Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField
    postname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = // I want to store the logged in admin full name here
```

Comment: try django signals

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below.

1. Create a middleware that will store the context of the current user to a local thread. Add this middleware to the bottom of middlewares list in settings.

```py
import threading


local = threading.local()


class BaseMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        local.user = request.user
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

2. Use local thread to get current user and store it in db white creating and updating post.

```py
from .middleware import local


class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField
    postname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="%(class)s_created_by_user",
    )
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="%(class)s_updated_by_user",
    )


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (
            self.pk is None
            and hasattr(local, "user")
            and local.user.__class__ != AnonymousUser
        ):
            self.created_by = local.user
        elif (
            self.pk
            and hasattr(local, "user")
            and local.user.__class__ != AnonymousUser
        ):
            self.updated_by = local.user

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```